# Get the current array key in a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array, key, shopping-cart

I have a session array *$_SESSION['cart']* with some items in it. The structure ist like this (via *print_r*):

```
    Array (
      [2-1] => Array (
         [color] => 7
         [articlenumber] => WRG70 10
         [quantity] => 1
         [price] => 17.50
      )

      [3-8] => Array (
         [color] => 2
         [articlenumber] => QRG50 02
         [quantity] => 1
         [price] => 13.50
      )
   )
```

Looping over the values for display is fine ...

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item_array)
{ 
   foreach($item_array as $item => $value)
   {   
      echo $value . ' | ';
   }
}
```

... since it results in something like this:

```
7 | WRG70 10 | 1 | 17.50 |
2 | QRG50 02 | 1 | 13.50 |
```

**But Now:** 
How can I output the matching key (e.g. '2-1') as well? I tried some array functions like *key()* & *current* but couldn't get it to work (one of these days).

Any quick hint on this?

Thanks a lot and best from Berlin

Fabian

Comment: `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item_key => $item_array)` then `$item_key` will contain `2-1`, `3-8`, etc..

Answer (score 3):

`foreach ($array as $key => $value) {...}`

I see you're already using this in the inner foreach loop, add it to the outer one as well, and you'll have access to the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item_array)
{ 
   foreach($item_array as $item => $value)
   {   
      echo 'Key = ' . $key . ' Value = ' . $value . ' | ';
   }
}
```